# Fluid width section between fixed width ones with text-overflow ellipsis

Tags: fluid-layout, css

I am having a great deal of difficulty reconciling these elements..

Here is a visual explanation of what I need to do. The tricky part is because I want one element to be 72px, another to be 10px, and the other to take up 'the rest'.

[image]

Here is my first attempt:
http://jsfiddle.net/cutcopypaste/7gXRg/

HTML:

```
<ul id="albums" class="rows">
    <li>
      <a>
        <img class="thumb" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
        <span>
          <em>An item with a great deal of text that continues on and on but should not wrap to a new line</em>
          <strong>Short content</strong>
         </span>
       </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>
        <img class="thumb" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
        <span>
          <em>Some ofr words,</em>
          <strong>An item with a great deal of text that continues on and on but should not wrap to a new line</strong>
         </span>
       </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>
        <img class="thumb" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
        <span>
          <em>This and That and that and this and what and for and never you miss</em>
          <strong>Johnnyycakes</strong>
         </span>
       </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is attempting with tables, but it's really not seeming to work!
http://jsfiddle.net/cutcopypaste/PwBms/

Only webkit support is required.

Comment: If this is only for up-to-date webkit, I would go with [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).  I'd put a demo together for you, but I'm crunched for time right now.